# Router Guards in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards, candeactivate

I created an application where the user inputs data. On that application, I want to implement router guards to deny the user to go back on-page so that they don't lose their data. If the user clicks on the back button on the browser, it reloads page instead of going back?

I am thinking to use canDeactivate to deny access to the previous page and Angular Location to determine what page users are on then reload that page. But I don't how to implement this.

Comment: https://medium.com/better-programming/angular-how-keep-user-from-lost-his-data-by-accidentally-leaving-the-page-before-submit-4eeb74420f0d

Comment: Why don't you store the datas somewhere instead?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The article that @MS_AU provided a link to looks like a pretty solid starting point!

Comment: @Narm I actually looked into this article https://medium.com/engineering-on-the-incline/reloading-current-route-on-click-angular-5-1a1bfc740ab2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1. Create Service for CanDeactivate Guard

First you have to create an interface that will declare `canDeactivate` method and using this interface you will create a service that will act as `canDeactivate` guard. This service will define `canDeactivate` method as following:

deactivate.guard.ts:

```cpp
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';

export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
  canDeactivate(): boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class DeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate): boolean {

    /*
    The return value would be true, unless the canActivate function, 
    defined on the component returns false,
    in which case the function will open a Dialog Box,
    to ask if we want to stay on the page or leave the page.
    */
    if (component.canDeactivate()) return true;
    else return confirm('You have unsaved changes!') ? true : false;

  }
}
```

The interface has declared `canDeactivate` method whose return type is  boolean.  In the service code, we called `canDeactivate` method using component instance.

## 2. Configure CanDeactivate Guard Service in Application Routing Module

app.module.ts:

```cpp
import { CanDeactivateGuard } from './can-deactivate-guard.service';

------
@NgModule({
  ------
  providers: [ 
    CanDeactivateGuard
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

## 3. Create canDeactivate() method within Your Component

formComponent.ts:

```cpp
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { CanComponentDeactivate } from 'src/app/deactivate.guard';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})
export class FormComponent implements CanComponentDeactivate {
  saved: boolean;
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: ['']
    });
  }

  /* Prevent page reloading */
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  canReload(e) {
    if (!this.canDeactivate()) e.returnValue = true;
  }

  submit = () => this.saved = true;
  canDeactivate = () => this.saved || !this.form.dirty;
}
```

## 4. Add CanDeactivate Guard to Component Route in Routing Module

You need to add our CanDeactivate guard .i.e. DeactivateGuard to component route in routing module using canDeactivate attribute.

app-routing.module.ts:

```cpp
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: FormComponent,
    canDeactivate: [DeactivateGuard]
  },
  { path: 'next', component: NextComponent },

  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

You might as well consider storing your data in a service as it might be a better choice.

Comment: You're totally right let me see what I can do about it

Comment: I've updated the answer, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: can I do this for multiple pages?

Comment: let me understand what you want. as far as understood you want your page to refresh on back navigation,  How do you expect the data to be saved?
a better approach is to prevent reloading or any page navigation when there's unsaved data.

Comment: Thanks I was actually trying different options but I think it would be best to prevent any page navigation

Comment: if (this.canDeactivate()) return; this doesn't make sense?

Comment: Unless you return false the the page will be reloaded

Comment: I've tried this and window alert comes up when i go next page  but doesnt give any alert when i go back

Comment: could you post your DeactiveGuard? it worked for me.

Comment: ```export class DeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate): boolean {

    if (component.canDeactivate()) return true;
    else return confirm('You have unsaved changes!') ? true : false;

  }
}

```